# OSX cross compiling library for ARMv7

Tags: ios, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile a library for an iOS application and I receive the following error message:

```
creating cache ./config.cache
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv7
checking whether the C compiler (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch armv7  ) works... no
configure: error: installation or configuration problem: C compiler cannot create executables.
```

Any ideas why the armv7 compiler can't create executables but it works for i386 and x86_64? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

What library?

I'm guessing OpenSSL by the looks of it (`BSD-generic32` is telltale), and if so, just use [OpenSSL-for-iPhone](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) to build it.

The important bits for helping to select the right build are in the build-libssl.sh script there, if you are curious.

UPDATE:

Sometimes, specifying the `-arch` isn't enough. It's helpful to pass the entire `-target`, especially when compiling C libraries, or libraries that are usually deployed on unix-type systems.

Try `clang -target arm64-apple-ios ...` and `clang -target armv7-apple-ios ...`, and then use `lipo` to merge the libraries into one with multiple architecture support.

You can try out possible target triples (and inspect the defines produced by them, if you're curious) with `clang -target armv7-apple-ios -dM -E - < /dev/null|less`, for e.g.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I fixed the BSD-generic32 issue. I already built OpenSSL. I'm now trying to build another library that uses OpenSSL to perform https requests (TCLink). I'm new to this and confused as to why the compiler won't produce executables for ARMv7.